# Perl Regex to Convert {a, b, c, ..., x} into (a|b|c|...|x)

Tags: regex, perl, wildcard

I am learning Perl and practicing regexes and I want to have the following functionality:

### Input

Wildcard style shell syntax

### Output

Perl regex

I am well aware of Regexp::Wildcards but I want something smaller and I also want to write it myself for the educational benefit.

I am really stuck trying to write the regex for this. I have tried to list my requirements to help make the regex pattern reveal itself:

- Start matching at a {
- Keep a backreference to each comma-separated element, get rid of padded spaces
- End matching at a }

However, this just introduced more questions in my mind

- How do I keep backreferences to an arbitrarily long list?

### Example

Suppose the input is `{foo, bar}.c`. The substitute operator should transform this to `(foo|bar).c`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't keep a dynamic list of back references.

Instead, you break up this problem into steps:

```
my $string = "{a, b, c, d, ..., x}";

if ($string =~ m/\{(.*?)\}/) {
    my $str = join '|', split /,\s*/, $1;
    print "($str)";
}
```

Outputs:

```
(a|b|c|d|...|x)
```

It's also possible to do this using a double layer search and replace, like so:

```
$string =~ s{\{(.*?)\}}{
    my $list = $1;
    $list =~ s/,\s*/|/g;
    "($list)"
}eg;

print $string;
```

Comment: Awesome. Never thought of layering regexes, but I guess it makes sense since the replacement expression can be just about anything. I'll upvote this once I have 15 rep ;)

Comment: Think will be better if you use s{\{([^}]*?)\}} instead of s{\{(.*?)\}} so you can put several lists in the same string.

Comment: Non-greedy matching already accomplishes that.  The only edge case that might be of concern is if the list could span new lines, in which case the /a modifier would be needed.

Comment: Join-Split? That was fun (and effective), +1. Next time maybe you can show us a Split-Join-Split. :)